# Need help understanding deposit event

Tags: polkadot, balances

At block 9987733, 1zugcacYFxX3HveFpJVUShjfb3KyaomfVqMTFoxYuUWCdD8 received 11.0711047073 DOT as signaled by a balances/Deposit event ([event link](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/9987733-0?event=9987733-562)).

I don't understand why that account received that money at that block, usually the source of the money is the event's signer but that specific event is unsigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because that account [reported a GRANDPA equivocation](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/9598517-2) and the slash was enacted.

Comment: Thanks! How can I find who got slashed? I assume that the slashed account would be the one that paid 11.0711047073 DOT to 1zug

Comment: I get it now, the source of funds is newly issued money.

Comment: It's not newly issued DOT, it's a percentage (I believe 10 or 20%) of the total slash. You can see who was slashed by the `identity` in the equivocation report.

Comment: I guess the source of funds is open to interpretation: slashed money is burnt, then some of the burnt money is sent to the reporter, so it either comes from the burnt money (and is therefore newly issued again) or from the reporter

Comment: Slashes are not burnt, they get sent [to the treasury](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.20/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L571)